# Angular JS: Directive to change all links within a block of html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using an angular directive is there a way to add target="_blank" to all `<a>` tags within a large block of HTML that i am pulling from a third party CMS?

Something like:

`<div ng-bind-html="post.body" updatelinks></div>`

Comment: You could probably write this as a filter, instead of a directive.

Comment: `angular.element('div').find('a').attr('target', '_blank')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest directive would look like this:

```
app.directive('updatelinks', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $timeout(function() {
                element.find('a').prop('target', '_blank');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: logging element returns [ <div ng-bind-html="post.body"  updatelinks=""></div>]
However logging element.find('a') returns [] ?

Comment: Right, I forgot that there is `ng-bind-html` which is executed after updatelinks directive. See updated code, which will work in this case.